# python Scopage of a function output within gameloop not evaluating

Tags: python, scope, conditional-statements, tic-tac-toe, game-loop

My problem is, after calling the function `check_win` in the `gameloop`,
even though the function evaluates false(I've checked so this is the
case), I assign this false value to `gamePlaying` inside the loop,
however the game loop `gamePlaying` conditional still evaluates true
and keeps going.

```
def check_win(): #function checks for three in a row across, down, and diagonals
        for x in range (0, 3) :
            y = x*3
            if (board[y] == board[(y + 1)] and board[y] == board[(y + 2)]):
                gamePlaying = False
            else:
                gamePlaying = True
            if (board[x] == board[(x + 3)] and board[x] == board[(x + 6)]):
                gamePlaying = False
            else:
                gamePlaying = True
            if((board[0] == board[4] and board[0] == board[8]) or 
                (board[2] == board[4] and board[4] == board[6])):
                gamePlaying = False
            else:
                gamePlaying = True
        return(gamePlaying)

    currentPlayer = [first_player,second_player] #creates list to iterate over turns
    gamePlaying = True #bool for gameloop

    while gamePlaying: #main game loop
        for i in currentPlayer: #iterates over current player to switch turns

            draw_board()
            place_move = int(input(first_move + ' what is your move? ')) #inputs then places move for first_player
            board[place_move] = first_player
            gamePlaying = check_win() #should take bool output of check_win and store to cont or end gameloop

            draw_board()
            place_move = int(input(second_move + ' what is your move? ')) #inputs then places move for second_player
            board[place_move] = second_player
            gamePlaying = Check_win() #should take bool output of check_win and store to cont or end gameloop
```

Comment: that other check win shouldnt be capitalized but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `if` statements when you mean to use `elif`. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

However, what you probably want to do is `return False` at those points since that would allow the function to exit early and you would have to worry that `gamePlaying` gets set back to `True` by later `if` statements.